# Default drawing for WM_PAINT in a memory DC

Tags: c, winapi, wndproc

I want to treat `WM_PAINT` message. But at first, I want to let  system to do the default drawing, then I draw something else manually.

For example:

```
    case WM_PAINT:
        CallWindowProc(DefWndProcTabControl, hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        TabControlOnPaint(hwnd);
        return 0;
```

This works, but is not very good, since it flicks.

One possibility is to make the default drawing done in a memory DC. But I don't know how to do this if I use `CallWindowProc(DefWndProcTabControl...)`.

Any suggestion for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the window you're painting supports it, use [`WM_PRINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd145216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`WM_PRINTCLIENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd145217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to do the default painting into a memory DC.

(Trying to do that via `CallWindowProc` is unlikely to work.)

Comment: Would you give a little bit more explanation? I am not sure, but does `WM_PRINT` or `WM_PRINTCLIENT` "print" something on the screen to a (memory) DC? If so, how to use them to do the default drawing (which is not done yet and not shown on the screen). Thank you very much.

Comment: @user565739: MSDN: "The WM_PRINT message is sent to a window to request that it draw itself in the specified device context".  So you use `SendMessage` to send `WM_PRINT` to `hwnd`, passing it a memory DC, and it paints itself into that DC.